# Hashtable class is missing in llvm libc++

Tags: android-ndk, libstdc++, libc++

I am doing the migration of standard library in my Android projects from gnustl (libstdc++) to llvm-libc++. 
and in one of the project, I am getting multiple errors of the missing header file,

```
  fatal error: 'hashtable.h' file not found
#include "hashtable.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang++.exe: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Android clang version 5.0.300080  (based on LLVM 5.0.300080)
```

Preprocessed file output revealed that this file is supplied by gnustl

```
.. f:/nugetcache/androidndk.16.1.1/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward\\hashtable.h
```

But after I have migrated to libc++ I could not find the equivalent header in libc++. This header file declares class HashTable

```
template<class _Val, class _Key, class _HashFcn,
       class _ExtractKey, class _EqualKey, class _Alloc>
    class hashtable
    {...}
```

I tried searching for this header and this class in libc++ code but could not find anything. I think this is an important class and must be provided by libc++ in some form but I could not identify it.

Has anyone faced error due to this discrepancy and what is the suggested work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried searching for this header and this class in libc++ code but could not find anything. I think this is an important class and must be provided by libc++ in some form but I could not identify it.

This is a libstdc++ extension, left over from pre-C++11 days.

If you take a look at the contents [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable.h), you'll see that it has a comment at the top says: *This is an internal header file, included by other library headers. Do not attempt to use it directly.*

Answer (score 0):

libc++ does not contain that header file and contains more specific interfaces for different classes of maps.

Hence @marshall was right in pointing that out, having said that we don't need that header at all.